# SVG image is not rendering in browsers except ie

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have menu toggle image SVG format. I'm adding it my html but it's not showing properly.

Here is views for explorer and chrome

[image: explorer]   [image: chrome]

Here is the svg

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="24.000000pt" height="31.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 24.000000 31.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,31.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
 fill="#000000" stroke="none">
```

Here my html

```css
.sidebar-toggle {
    float: left;
    background: url('menucursor.svg') no-repeat !important;
    padding: 2px 10px 0 3px;
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" href="#" role="button"></a>
```

When i try to use `background-image` attribute is not accepting from browser.

Is there any way to show it properly?

Comment: can you share the svg of that menucursor? since we can't see the svg from here, if you have online link then kindly share it here.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Manjuboyz I added my svg

Comment: Can you add all these into fiddler or something as a reproducible product? I still couldn't get it running.

Comment: @Manjuboyz i added code snipped but i don't know how to addsvg image if you know you can added it. Still i cannot show my svg file

Answer (score -2):

Since your anchor a has no child elements it cannot take space in your dom. You will have to explicitly assign your dimensions:

```
.sidebar-toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px; //Change this to whatever meets your needs, I suggest the actual width of the svg.
  height: 20px; //Change this to whatever meets your needs, I suggest the actual height of the svg.
  background-size: 100% 100%; //Or background-size: cover; or background-size: contain;
  float: left;
  background: url(../../assets/images/icons/menucursor.svg) no-repeat !important;
  padding: 2px 10px 0 3px;
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why the image is there in IE but not in other browsers.

Comment: Also explicit dimensions are not required since the padding will determine the element's size.